# Как узнать, какие порты нужно пробросить при использовании Java ServerSocket?

Tags: java, сервер

Приветствую всех! У меня следующая проблема: есть сервер на Java, использующий для работы ServerSocket , к которому подключаются несколько клиентов. В пределах моего роутера все прекрасно работает. Но с пробросом портов есть проблема. Как я понял, ServerSocket всего лишь перебрасывает каждого клиента на отдельный Socket, который висит уже на другом порту. ServerSocket открыт у меня на порту 1950,

`socket.getRemoteSocketAddress()`

в клиенте выдает это: /192.168.152.248:50759 . Как я могу заранее узнать, что у новый клиент будет подключен именно по порту 50759? Может быть есть какой-то определенный диапазон, который нужно пробросить? А может быть есть вариант использования upnp? Понятно, что нужно как минимум пробросить 1950 порт, он у меня проброшен, но клиенты все равно не могут подключиться к серверу.

Comment: Вы неправильно понимаете. Для установления подключения нужно создать две пары адрес:порт - одну у клиента, другую у сервера. То, что вы видите - автоматически созданная пара на калиенте, а не на сервере. Вы же сами вызываете метод с названием get **remote** address, откуда там быть адресу сервера?

Comment: Ну то, что айпишники разные - это понятно. То есть все равно в моем случае получается, что клиент коннектится с порта 50759 на порт 1950 на сервере? Тогда все равно интересно, что я не так делаю, если порт 1950 проброшен, а клиенты не могут приконнектиться к моему серверу из интернета, хотя на локалхосте и в пределах моего роутера все работает.

Comment: @alexbayker А "белый" ли у Вас на сервере айпишник?

Comment: Благодарю всех за помощь! С роутером что-то не так было. Роутер другой подкинул - все заработало. Сбросил настройки на первом - вроде тоже коннектится.